# How to get role's permissions using RESTlet in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I want to get all the options for my role.

Example :
i have attached the role's page image. i need the following permissions using RESTlet code.

1. List->Permissions and its level
2. Setup->Permissions and its level

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the most part you should be able to use:

```
nlapiGetContext().getPermission('permission_id')
```

to access the current role permissions. There is a full list of accessible permissions in the NetSuite Help Center.  Search for: "Permission Names and IDs".

> I need lead, prospect, customer, other name and contact also..

Lead, Prospect, and Customer records are all the same permission  `LIST_CUSTJOB`

Other name is `LIST_OTHERNAME`

Contact in `LIST_CONTACT`

You can extract permission id's not listed in the help center by viewing the xml body of the role records.  Append `&xml=t` to the url of any role(or record) in NS. eg:
`https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/setup/role.nl?id=1008&e=T&xml=t`

Find the appropriate permission list, and try your permission value out. It's all outside the documentation, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i already tried this. i could get Partner(LIST_PARTNER), Vendor(LIST VENDOR) , Company(LIST_COMPANY). I need lead, prospect, customer, other name and contact also. There is no permission id for mentioned relationships

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do but if you need to find a specific permission id you can guess. 
e.g. If I log in with a restricted role and, in a console window, type `nlapiGetContext().getPermission("LIST_CONTACT");` this returns 4 -- full permission. If you test something non-existent or for which you have no access you'll get a 0: `nlapiGetContext().getPermission("LIST_FRIDGE") or nlapiGetContext().getPermission("LIST_COMPANY")` both of these return 0. NOTE: when you test as Admin or Full Access you always get a 4 even if the permission doesn't exist so you have to use a restricted role

Comment: This is an excellent point.  Testing with an admin/full user will not help out at all.   I've added the specific permission ids requested, and described the method for uncovering them.